# I use MPAndroidChart and I need callbacks when clicking values, how to do that?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

this is my cod....
Here you can see the [library's](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) classes
I've deleted some unnecessary code

```
        final LineChart lineChart = (LineChart)findViewById(R.id.chart);
        final List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Entry> entries1 = new ArrayList<>();
        Button btn_n1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_n1);
        btn_n1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (e_x1.getText().toString().equals("")||e_y1.getText().toString().equals("")){

                }
                else {
                    entries.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(e_x1.getText().toString()), Float.parseFloat(e_y1.getText().toString())));
                }
            }
        });
```

This button takes the values of two text boxes....

```
        Button btn_n2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_n2);
        btn_n2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (e_x2.getText().toString().equals("")||e_y2.getText().toString().equals("")){

                }
                else {
                    entries1.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(e_x2.getText().toString()),Float.parseFloat(e_y2.getText().toString())));
                }

            }
        });
```

i clear some thing that no need to see
what can i say.....i hate error

```
        Button btn_draw =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_draw);
        btn_draw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                    LineDataSet dataSet1 = new LineDataSet(entries, "#First Curve");
                    dataSet1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    LineDataSet dataSet2 = new LineDataSet(entries1, "#Second Curve");
                    dataSet2.setColor(Color.RED);
                    List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
                    dataSets.add(dataSet1);
                    dataSets.add(dataSet2);
                    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
                    lineChart.setData(data);
                    lineChart.animateX(2000);
                    lineChart.invalidate();

                }


            }
        });
```